# On the behavior of $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ for $t\in(-14,14)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Denote by $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function.
Since $\zeta(1/2 + it)\neq 0$ for $|t|\leq 14$, it *seems* to follow that $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ is either strictly decreasing or strictly increasing on $(-14,14)$. But what **exactly** is the behaviour of $|\zeta(1/2 +it)|$ on this region ? I mean, is it strictly increasing or is it strictly decreasing ?

A graphical sketch might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't follow that $\lvert \zeta(1/2 + it) \rvert$ is strictly increasing or decreasing.

In fact, since $\lvert \zeta(1/2 + it)\rvert = \lvert \zeta(1/2 - it) \rvert$ from the functional equation, one cannot have that $\lvert \zeta(1/2 + it) \rvert$ is strictly increasing or decreasing at $0$, since the function is symmetric there.

One can plot this readily using something like sage, or something online like [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(zeta(1%2F2+%2B+it))+for+t+in+%5B-14,+14%5D). You get the following plot.

[image]